# How to draw polygon in Google map Flutter dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-api-3

I need to create polygons on the Google map dynamically in flutter. I could plot polygons with known points but I couldn't draw the polygons dynamically Please help...

Comment: By dynamically, do you mean you want to draw polygons with unknown points?

Comment: I have to draw polygon on map , similar to drawing polygon in google mymaps.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a functionality similar to this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools but in Flutter?

Comment: @jabamataro yes same functionality in flutter

Comment: Are you trying to build this on Android and iOS?

Comment: For both ideally, but right now focussing on android only

Comment: How can I draw polygons on google maps flutter at my current position:

Answer (score 1):

I also need to draw a polygon point by point.
To do this, in the onTap handler

```
GoogleMap(
    polygons: Set<Polygon>.of(mapsPolygons.values),
    onTap: tapMap,
    ...
)
```

I add a marker and write each tap down to the `List<LatLng>`.
Then I update the map, with the rendered polygon

```
Map<PolygonId, Polygon> mapsPolygons = <PolygonId, Polygon>{};
List<LatLng> mapsPolygons = [];

void tapMap(LatLng pos) {
  final PolygonId polygonId = PolygonId("Polgon_1");
  final Polygon polygon = Polygon(
    polygonId: polygonId,
    strokeColor: Colors.red,
    strokeWidth: 5,
    fillColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.3),
    points: polygonPoints,
  );
  mapsPolygons[polygonId] = polygon;
  
  //setState((){});
}
```

i update the map using `StreamBuilder()` but it should work with `setState()` too

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxJ5F.gif)

*P.S. Sorry for my English*